# Why `Assertion failed` occurred using opencv java desktop version?

Tags: java, opencv, bufferedimage

Here is my code that course the `Assertion failed`:

```
BufferedImage objImg = ImageIO.read(new File("myfilePath/myobj.png"));
byte[] objImgPixels = ((DataBufferByte) objImg.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
Mat read_mat = new Mat();
read_mat.put(0, 0, ObjImgPixels);
Mat img_object = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(read_mat, img_object, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
```

And the whole error log:

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor.`

But I tried to replace my `img_object` with this:

`Mat img_object = Highgui.imread("myfilePath/myobj.png", 0);`

It is successful. So, I would like to know what's going wrong with my code? And recommend? Thanks.

Comment: Try googling: http://answers.opencv.org/question/10470/why-this-error-in-cvtcolor-function-happens/

Comment: imho, `Mat read_mat = new Mat();` should be : `Mat read_mat = new Mat(h,w,CvType.CV_8UC3);`